# ld error: skipping incompatible.../gst/lib/libgstreamer-0.10.so when searching for -lgstreamer-0.10 .Hot to fix?

Tags: qt4, cross-compiling, gstreamer, qt4.7

I'm trying to cross-compile qt4 for an embedded system. My embedded system is based on armv5 and my host PC has got a i686-32bit architecture.

This is the command that I use to configure evrything:

```
 make confclean;PKG_CONFIG_PATH=home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/armle-fs/lib/pkgconfig ./configure -embedded arm -fast -fontconfig -I/home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/armle-fs/usr/include/freetype2/freetype/config  -gstreamer -little-endian -no-3dnow -no-accessibility -no-avx -no-cups -no-dbus -no-declarative -no-declarative-debug -no-exceptions -no-g++-exceptions -no-gif -no-javascript-jit -no-largefile -no-libmng -no-libtiff -nomake demos -nomake examples -no-mitshm -no-mmx -no-multimedia -no-nas-sound -no-neon -no-nis -no-opengl -no-openssl -no-openvg -no-qt3support -no-script -no-scripttools -no-sm -no-sql-sqlite -no-sse -no-sse2 -no-sse3 -no-sse4.1 -no-sse4.2 -no-ssse3 -no-stl -no-svg -no-webkit -no-xfixes -no-xinerama -no-xinput -no-xkb -no-xmlpatterns -no-xshape -no-xsync -no-xvideo -opensource -phonon -phonon-backend -prefix /home/user/ev-sdk/workspace/evelin-bsp/binaries/usr/share/qt_eng -qt-mouse-tslib -qt-zlib -reduce-relocations -release -svg -v -xplatform qws/linux-arm-g++ -lglib-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lgstreamer-0.10 -I/home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/armle-fs/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/armle-fs/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/home/user/ev-sdk/workspace/evelin-bsp/binaries/usr/share/gst/include/gstreamer-0.10 -I/home/user/ev-sdk/workspace/evelin-bsp/binaries/usr/share/libxml2/include/libxml2 -L/home/user/ev-sdk/workspace/evelin-bsp/binaries/usr/share/gst/lib -L/home/user/ev-sdk/workspace/evelin-bsp/binaries/usr/share/libxml2/lib -L/home/user/ev-sdk/workspace/evelin-bsp/binaries/usr/share/gst/lib/gstreamer-0.10 -I/home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/armle-fs/usr/include -L/home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/armle-fs/usr/lib -force-pkg-config -qt-gfx-transformed  ;make
```

This is the output:

```
b2 -t imx25 g++ -m32 -Wl,-O1 -o alsa alsatest.o     -L/home/user/ev-sdk/workspace/evelin-bsp/binaries/usr/share/gst/lib -L/home/user/ev-sdk/workspace/evelin-bsp/binaries/usr/share/libxml2/lib -L/home/user/ev-sdk/workspace/evelin-bsp/binaries/usr/share/gst/lib/gstreamer-0.10 -L/home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/armle-fs/usr/lib -lglib-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lgstreamer-0.10 -lasound 
alsa enabled.
Stdint auto-detection... ()
sb2 -t imx25 g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W  -I../../../mkspecs/qws/linux-arm-g++ -I. -I/home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/armle-fs/usr/include/freetype2/freetype/config -I/home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/armle-fs/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/armle-fs/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/home/user/ev-sdk/workspace/evelin-bsp/binaries/usr/share/gst/include/gstreamer-0.10 -I/home/user/ev-sdk/workspace/evelin-bsp/binaries/usr/share/libxml2/include/libxml2 -I/home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/armle-fs/usr/include -o main.o main.cpp
sb2 -t imx25 g++ -m32 -Wl,-O1 -o stdint main.o     -L/home/user/ev-sdk/workspace/evelin-bsp/binaries/usr/share/gst/lib -L/home/user/ev-sdk/workspace/evelin-bsp/binaries/usr/share/libxml2/lib -L/home/user/ev-sdk/workspace/evelin-bsp/binaries/usr/share/gst/lib/gstreamer-0.10 -L/home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/armle-fs/usr/lib -lglib-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lgstreamer-0.10 
Stdint enabled.
Testing size of pointers ... (/nfs_gea/Sorgenti_librerie/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.4/mkspecs/qws/linux-arm-g++ yes /nfs_gea/Sorgenti_librerie/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.4 /nfs_gea/Sorgenti_librerie/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.4)
rm -f ptrsizetest.o
rm -f *~ core *.core
sb2 -t imx25 g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W  -I../../../mkspecs/qws/linux-arm-g++ -I. -o ptrsizetest.o ptrsizetest.cpp
ptrsizetest.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
ptrsizetest.cpp:59: error: 'PointerSize' is not a member of 'QPointerSizeTest<4>'
make: *** [ptrsizetest.o] Error 1
Pointer size: 4
ln: creating symbolic link `/nfs_gea/Sorgenti_librerie/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.4/include/QtCore/qconfig.h': File exists
ln: creating symbolic link `/nfs_gea/Sorgenti_librerie/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.4/include/Qt/qconfig.h': File exists

Building on:   qws/linux-x86-g++
Building for:  qws/linux-arm-g++
Architecture:  arm
Host architecture: i386

qmake vars .......... cat: .qmake.vars: No such file or directory
qmake switches ......... 
Build .................. libs docs translations
Configuration ..........  cross_compile release shared dll embedded precompile_header exceptions_off  minimal-config small-config medium-config large-config full-config phonon phonon-backend embedded ipv6 clock-gettime clock-monotonic mremap getaddrinfo ipv6ifname getifaddrs inotify system-jpeg no-mng system-png png no-gif no-tiff freetype zlib glib gstreamer alsa audio-backend svg release
Debug .................. no
Qt 3 compatibility ..... no
QtDBus module .......... no
QtConcurrent code ...... yes
QtGui module ........... yes
QtScript module ........ no
QtScriptTools module ... no
QtXmlPatterns module ... no
Phonon module .......... yes
Multimedia module ...... no
SVG module ............. yes
WebKit module .......... no
Declarative module ..... no
Support for S60 ........ no
Symbian DEF files ...... no
STL support ............ no
PCH support ............ yes
MMX/3DNOW/SSE/SSE2/SSE3. no/no/no/no/no
SSSE3/SSE4.1/SSE4.2..... no/no/no
AVX..................... no
iWMMXt support ......... no
NEON support ........... no
IPv6 support ........... yes
IPv6 ifname support .... yes
getaddrinfo support .... yes
getifaddrs support ..... yes
Accessibility .......... no
NIS support ............ no
CUPS support ........... no
Iconv support .......... no
Glib support ........... yes
GStreamer support ...... yes
PulseAudio support ..... no
Large File support ..... no
GIF support ............ no
TIFF support ........... no
JPEG support ........... plugin (system)
PNG support ............ yes (system)
MNG support ............ no
zlib support ........... yes
Session management ..... no
Embedded support ....... arm
Freetype2 support ...... auto (yes)
Graphics (qt) .......... linuxfb multiscreen transformed
Graphics (plugin) ...... 
Decorations (qt) ....... styled windows default
Decorations (plugin) ... 
Keyboard driver (qt) ... tty
Keyboard driver (plugin) .. 
Mouse driver (qt) ...... pc linuxtp tslib
Mouse driver (plugin) .. 
OpenGL support ......... no
OpenVG support ......... no
ODBC support ........... plugin
SQLite 2 support ....... plugin
OpenSSL support ........ no 
Alsa support ........... yes
ICD support ............ no



  ...........
ar cqs libbootstrap.a .obj/release-static-emb-arm/qisciicodec.o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/qlatincodec.o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/qsimplecodec.o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/qtextcodec.o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/qtsciicodec.o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/qutfcodec.o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/qglobal.o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/qmalloc.o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/qnumeric.o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/qabstractfileengine.o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/qbuffer.o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/qdatastream.o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/qdir.o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/qdiriterator.o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/qfile.o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/qfileinfo.o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/qfsfileengine.o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/qfsfileengine_iterator.o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/qiodevice.o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/qtemporaryfile.o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/qtextstream.o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/qurl.o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/qmetatype.o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/qvariant.o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/qbitarray.o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/qbytearray.o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/qbytearraymatcher.o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/qdatetime.o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/qhash.o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/qlist.o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/qlocale.o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/qmap.o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/qregexp.o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/qstring.o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/qstringlist.o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/qvector.o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/qvsnprintf.o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/qxmlutils.o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/qxmlstream.o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/qdom.o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/qxml.o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/qfsfileengine_unix.o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/qfsfileengine_iterator_unix.o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/adler32.o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/compress.o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/crc32.o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/deflate.o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/gzio.o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/inffast.o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/inflate.o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/inftrees.o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/trees.o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/uncompr.o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/zutil.o
make[1]: Leaving directory `/nfs_gea/Sorgenti_librerie/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.4/src/tools/bootstrap'
cd src/tools/moc/ && make -f Makefile 
make[1]: Entering directory `/nfs_gea/Sorgenti_librerie/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.4/src/tools/moc'
/nfs_gea/Sorgenti_librerie/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.4/bin/qmake -spec ../../../mkspecs/qws/linux-x86-g++ -o Makefile moc.pro
make[1]: Leaving directory `/nfs_gea/Sorgenti_librerie/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.4/src/tools/moc'
make[1]: Entering directory `/nfs_gea/Sorgenti_librerie/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.4/src/tools/moc'
g++ -c -pipe -I/home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/armle-fs/usr/include/freetype2/freetype/config -I/home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/armle-fs/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/armle-fs/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/home/user/ev-sdk/workspace/evelin-bsp/binaries/usr/share/gst/include/gstreamer-0.10 -I/home/user/ev-sdk/workspace/evelin-bsp/binaries/usr/share/libxml2/include/libxml2 -I/home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/armle-fs/usr/include -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -DQT_MOC -DQT_BOOTSTRAPPED -DQT_LITE_UNICODE -DQT_TEXTCODEC -DQT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_NO_CODECS -DQT_NO_DATASTREAM -DQT_NO_GEOM_VARIANT -DQT_NO_LIBRARY -DQT_NO_QOBJECT -DQT_NO_STL -DQT_NO_SYSTEMLOCALE -DQT_NO_TEXTSTREAM -DQT_NO_THREAD -DQT_NO_UNICODETABLES -DQT_NO_USING_NAMESPACE -I../../../mkspecs/qws/linux-x86-g++ -I. -I. -I. -I../../../include -I../../../include/QtCore -I../../../include/QtXml -I../../xml -o release-shared/moc.o moc.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -I/home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/armle-fs/usr/include/freetype2/freetype/config -I/home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/armle-fs/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/armle-fs/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/home/user/ev-sdk/workspace/evelin-bsp/binaries/usr/share/gst/include/gstreamer-0.10 -I/home/user/ev-sdk/workspace/evelin-bsp/binaries/usr/share/libxml2/include/libxml2 -I/home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/armle-fs/usr/include -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -DQT_MOC -DQT_BOOTSTRAPPED -DQT_LITE_UNICODE -DQT_TEXTCODEC -DQT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_NO_CODECS -DQT_NO_DATASTREAM -DQT_NO_GEOM_VARIANT -DQT_NO_LIBRARY -DQT_NO_QOBJECT -DQT_NO_STL -DQT_NO_SYSTEMLOCALE -DQT_NO_TEXTSTREAM -DQT_NO_THREAD -DQT_NO_UNICODETABLES -DQT_NO_USING_NAMESPACE -I../../../mkspecs/qws/linux-x86-g++ -I. -I. -I. -I../../../include -I../../../include/QtCore -I../../../include/QtXml -I../../xml -o release-shared/preprocessor.o preprocessor.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -I/home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/armle-fs/usr/include/freetype2/freetype/config -I/home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/armle-fs/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/armle-fs/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/home/user/ev-sdk/workspace/evelin-bsp/binaries/usr/share/gst/include/gstreamer-0.10 -I/home/user/ev-sdk/workspace/evelin-bsp/binaries/usr/share/libxml2/include/libxml2 -I/home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/armle-fs/usr/include -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -DQT_MOC -DQT_BOOTSTRAPPED -DQT_LITE_UNICODE -DQT_TEXTCODEC -DQT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_NO_CODECS -DQT_NO_DATASTREAM -DQT_NO_GEOM_VARIANT -DQT_NO_LIBRARY -DQT_NO_QOBJECT -DQT_NO_STL -DQT_NO_SYSTEMLOCALE -DQT_NO_TEXTSTREAM -DQT_NO_THREAD -DQT_NO_UNICODETABLES -DQT_NO_USING_NAMESPACE -I../../../mkspecs/qws/linux-x86-g++ -I. -I. -I. -I../../../include -I../../../include/QtCore -I../../../include/QtXml -I../../xml -o release-shared/generator.o generator.cpp
generator.cpp: In member function ‘void Generator::generateCode()’:
generator.cpp:284: warning: ignoring return value of ‘size_t fwrite(const void*, size_t, size_t, FILE*)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result
g++ -c -pipe -I/home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/armle-fs/usr/include/freetype2/freetype/config -I/home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/armle-fs/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/armle-fs/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/home/user/ev-sdk/workspace/evelin-bsp/binaries/usr/share/gst/include/gstreamer-0.10 -I/home/user/ev-sdk/workspace/evelin-bsp/binaries/usr/share/libxml2/include/libxml2 -I/home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/armle-fs/usr/include -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -DQT_MOC -DQT_BOOTSTRAPPED -DQT_LITE_UNICODE -DQT_TEXTCODEC -DQT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_NO_CODECS -DQT_NO_DATASTREAM -DQT_NO_GEOM_VARIANT -DQT_NO_LIBRARY -DQT_NO_QOBJECT -DQT_NO_STL -DQT_NO_SYSTEMLOCALE -DQT_NO_TEXTSTREAM -DQT_NO_THREAD -DQT_NO_UNICODETABLES -DQT_NO_USING_NAMESPACE -I../../../mkspecs/qws/linux-x86-g++ -I. -I. -I. -I../../../include -I../../../include/QtCore -I../../../include/QtXml -I../../xml -o release-shared/parser.o parser.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -I/home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/armle-fs/usr/include/freetype2/freetype/config -I/home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/armle-fs/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/armle-fs/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/home/user/ev-sdk/workspace/evelin-bsp/binaries/usr/share/gst/include/gstreamer-0.10 -I/home/user/ev-sdk/workspace/evelin-bsp/binaries/usr/share/libxml2/include/libxml2 -I/home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/armle-fs/usr/include -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -DQT_MOC -DQT_BOOTSTRAPPED -DQT_LITE_UNICODE -DQT_TEXTCODEC -DQT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_NO_CODECS -DQT_NO_DATASTREAM -DQT_NO_GEOM_VARIANT -DQT_NO_LIBRARY -DQT_NO_QOBJECT -DQT_NO_STL -DQT_NO_SYSTEMLOCALE -DQT_NO_TEXTSTREAM -DQT_NO_THREAD -DQT_NO_UNICODETABLES -DQT_NO_USING_NAMESPACE -I../../../mkspecs/qws/linux-x86-g++ -I. -I. -I. -I../../../include -I../../../include/QtCore -I../../../include/QtXml -I../../xml -o release-shared/token.o token.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -I/home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/armle-fs/usr/include/freetype2/freetype/config -I/home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/armle-fs/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/armle-fs/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/home/user/ev-sdk/workspace/evelin-bsp/binaries/usr/share/gst/include/gstreamer-0.10 -I/home/user/ev-sdk/workspace/evelin-bsp/binaries/usr/share/libxml2/include/libxml2 -I/home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/armle-fs/usr/include -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -DQT_MOC -DQT_BOOTSTRAPPED -DQT_LITE_UNICODE -DQT_TEXTCODEC -DQT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_NO_CODECS -DQT_NO_DATASTREAM -DQT_NO_GEOM_VARIANT -DQT_NO_LIBRARY -DQT_NO_QOBJECT -DQT_NO_STL -DQT_NO_SYSTEMLOCALE -DQT_NO_TEXTSTREAM -DQT_NO_THREAD -DQT_NO_UNICODETABLES -DQT_NO_USING_NAMESPACE -I../../../mkspecs/qws/linux-x86-g++ -I. -I. -I. -I../../../include -I../../../include/QtCore -I../../../include/QtXml -I../../xml -o release-shared/main.o main.cpp
    g++ -fno-exceptions -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-rpath,/home/user/ev-sdk/workspace/evelin-bsp/binaries/usr/share/qt_eng/lib -Wl,-rpath,/home/user/ev-sdk/workspace/evelin-bsp/binaries/usr/share/qt_eng/lib -o ../../../bin/moc release-shared/moc.o release-shared/preprocessor.o release-shared/generator.o release-shared/parser.o release-shared/token.o release-shared/main.o    -L/home/user/ev-sdk/workspace/evelin-bsp/binaries/usr/share/gst/lib -L/home/user/ev-sdk/workspace/evelin-bsp/binaries/usr/share/libxml2/lib -L/home/user/ev-sdk/workspace/evelin-bsp/binaries/usr/share/gst/lib/gstreamer-0.10 -L/home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/armle-fs/usr/lib -L/nfs_gea/Sorgenti_librerie/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.4/src/tools/bootstrap -lbootstrap -L/home/user/ev-sdk/workspace/evelin-bsp/binaries/usr/share/gst/lib -L/home/user/ev-sdk/workspace/evelin-bsp/binaries/usr/share/libxml2/lib -L/home/user/ev-sdk/workspace/evelin-bsp/binaries/usr/share/gst/lib/gstreamer-0.10 -L/home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/armle-fs/usr/lib -lglib-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lgstreamer-0.10 
    /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/armle-fs/usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so when searching for -lglib-2.0
    /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/armle-fs/usr/lib/libglib-2.0.a when searching for -lglib-2.0
    /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/armle-fs/usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so when searching for -lglib-2.0
    /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/armle-fs/usr/lib/libglib-2.0.a when searching for -lglib-2.0
    /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/armle-fs/usr/lib/libgthread-2.0.so when searching for -lgthread-2.0
    /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/armle-fs/usr/lib/libgthread-2.0.a when searching for -lgthread-2.0
    /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/armle-fs/usr/lib/libgthread-2.0.so when searching for -lgthread-2.0
    /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/armle-fs/usr/lib/libgthread-2.0.a when searching for -lgthread-2.0
    /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /home/user/ev-sdk/workspace/evelin-bsp/binaries/usr/share/gst/lib/libgstreamer-0.10.so when searching for -lgstreamer-0.10
    /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /home/user/ev-sdk/workspace/evelin-bsp/binaries/usr/share/gst/lib/libgstreamer-0.10.so when searching for -lgstreamer-0.10
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgstreamer-0.10
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    make[1]: *** [../../../bin/moc] Error 1
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/nfs_gea/Sorgenti_librerie/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.4/src/tools/moc'
    make: *** [sub-moc-make_default-ordered] Error 2
    user@ubuntu1004desktop:~/Desktop/nfs_gea/Sorgenti_librerie/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.4$
```

The problem is that the linker can't use libgstreamer-0.10.so and libglib-2.0.so libraries because it thinks they are incompatible for the target architecture.
So, it returns:

skipping incompatible /home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/armle-fs/usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so when searching for -lglib-2.0

and other similar errors.
But these libraries are compatible for the target architecture (arm), infact:

```
readelf -h /home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/armle-fs/usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              DYN (Shared object file)
  Machine:                           ARM
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0xef04
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          735080 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x4000002, has entry point, Version4 EABI
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         4
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         26
  Section header string table index: 25
```

So, how to fix the issue?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I see `-m32 ` in your build, `man g++` says that means to build for a 32-bit ABI, is that compatible with ARM? I don't even know. Probably is. But some option for how the `libglib-2.0.so` was built must be wrong

In any case, I had the same issue when I was trying to use Qt on Android Emulator (64-bit) so I had to use my ARM (32-bit) Android device via USB and then it used the *.so file just fine, so it is probably some sort of compatibility issue with how `libglib-2.0.so` was built